# Reference for a proof of theorem 6.3 in Numerical Optimization Nocedal

Tags: reference-request, optimization, numerical-optimization

On page 150 of Nocedal & Wright's [Numerical Optimization](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5) ([PDF](http://apmath.spbu.ru/cnsa/pdf/monograf/Numerical_Optimization2006.pdf)), there is no proof of theorem 6.3. I was hoping for someone to point me to the proof or alternative provided it. The theorem is

---

Suppose $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow  \mathbb R$ is strongly convex quadratic function $f(x) = 0.5x^TAx + b^Tx$ where $A$ is symmetric positive definite. Let $x_0$ be any starting point and $B_0$ be any symmetric positive definite matrix, and suppose that the matrices is $B_k$ are updated by the Broyden formula with $\phi_k \in [0,1]$. Define $\lambda_1 ^k\leq \lambda_2^k \leq \dots \leq \lambda_n^k $ the be the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$A^{1/2} B_k^{-1}A^{1/2}$$

then for all $k$ we have
$$\min\{\lambda_j^k,1\} \leq \lambda_j^{k+1} \leq \max\{\lambda_j^k,1\}$$
for $j=1,2,3,\dots,n$

---

Thank you, for your time and inputs, guys.

Comment: perhaps you can prove it yourself via the Sherman Morrison formula

Comment: I am not sure if we are thinking of the same theorem, but Sherman Morrison theorem gives me the inverse of a matrix, and I do not see how this is applicable here. Yes I know the inverse formula for $B_k$ but that does not tell me anything about the eigenvalues

Comment: It seems that [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-pdf/13/3/317/988678/130317.pdf) by Fletcher has some relevant discussion.